# How do i use the number assign in the function's parameter in a for loop

Tags: function, loops, for-loop, parameters

i am having trouble in assigning the number 'numTiles' to a for Loop in my code. It says that "An attempt was made to call a function with a parameter of an invalid type." How do i assign the number of times my for loop to run from the number i assigned when calling the function?

code:

```
def createSquareTile(numTiles, prefix):
  current = 1
  numTilesI = int(numTiles)
  for i in numTilesI:
    if current == 1:
      size = requestNumber("Please input a positive number")
      sizeI = int(size)
```

How do i use the number i assigned in numTiles when calling the function in my for loop? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution,

```
for i in range(numTilesI):
```